# T-SQL to show Azure SQL Managed Instance vs Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

Restated: How can I use T-SQL to determine whether a instance is an Azure SQL Managed Instance or Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To programmatically determine the engine edition, use SELECT
>   SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition'). This query will return '5' for single
>   databases/elastic pools and '8' for managed instances in Azure SQL
>   Database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017